# How to sort array of custom class using more than one property criteria?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting, keypathcomparator

How to sort an array by multiple properties?

Comment: Could you give an example? It's hard to imagine what you're thinking

Comment: Omg. I was just reading your answer on another thread. Yes. I will provide code. Please help! You are a legend.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a legend, but I'm not a mind reader :)

Comment: @CV3 Make yourself a favor and get rid of `ObjectMapper`. Google about `Codable` protocol

Comment: It is pretty straight forward. Plenty of examples on SO. Btw try using a struct instead of a class. And get rid of the implicit unwrapped optionals

Comment: Alexander - the full example code is there. Can you add anything to @LeoDabus answer or maybe advise regarding a separate solution? Thank you.

Comment: `struct SavedItemModel: Codable {` `let uid: String` `let title: String` `let savedOn: Date` `let kind: Kind` `enum Kind: String { case itemType1, itemType2, itemType3 }` `}`

Comment: "so how can I match the sorting of the 'arySavedUserItems' to the sorting of the 'arySavedUsers'?" You don't. I would say this data model just doesn't make sense. Having those 3 parallel arrays (`arySavedUsers`, `arySavedUserIDs` and `arySavedUserItems`) just makes everything really complex. I agree with Leo, you should rethink your data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [`KeyPathComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/keypathcomparator). You can pass as many properties as needed when sorting your collection:

```
let sorted = userItems.sorted(using: [.init(\.savedOn, order: .reverse), .init(\.title, order: .reverse)])
```